# Slice pandas DataFrame based on csv of lists

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file in the following format.

```
[1,2]
[3]
[4,5,6,7,10]
```

And I have a pandas `DataFrame` like following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                'path'  : ["p1,p2,p3,p4","p1,p2,p1","p1,p5,p5,p7","p1,p2,p3,p3","p1,p2","p1","p2,p3,p4"]})
```

output:

```
   id         path
0   1  p1,p2,p3,p4
1   2     p1,p2,p1
2   3  p1,p5,p5,p7
3   4  p1,p2,p3,p3
4   5        p1,p2
5   6           p1
6   7     p2,p3,p4
```

I want to slice the `DataFrame` based on the text file. What is the wrong with following? It produces empty DataFrames.

```
for line in lines:
    print line
    print df[df['id'].isin(line)]
```

But it works fine with following.

```
for line in lines:
    print df[df['id'].isin([1,2])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`line` is a string. `[1,2]` is a list. To convert the string to a list, you could use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
line = ast.literal_eval(line)
```

---

```
import ast
for line in lines:
    print line
    line = ast.literal_eval(line)
    print df.loc[df['id'].isin(line)]
```

PS. Although `df[boolean_mask]` works, I think `df.loc[boolean_mask]` is better because it does not require the reader to know the type of values in `boolean_mask` to understand which way the `df` is being sub-selected (by row or by column). `df.loc` is more explicit, and a tad faster.

Comment: Excellent..wasted lot of time on this. Thanks :)